# jQuery .post() not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, post

I have the following AJAX call through jQuery:

```
// var upload = some JSON data
$.post('/videos/upload', upload);
```

And this express.js API part to handle the request:

```
app.post('/videos/upload', function(request, response) {
    console.log('Request received')
}
```

However, when .post() is called, it does not seem to be executing. The request is nowhere to be seen in Firebug's Net logger, and the node.js console doesn't log anything, either.

When I type the request directly into the Firebug console, it executes just fine.

Using $.ajax() does not work, either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and see whether the line of code is really reached. Are the any other errors in the console?

Comment: Try using a full URL, instead of relative, just as a test.

Comment: @Banning there's nothing wrong with `$.post('/videos/upload', upload);` if `upload` is a querystring, object/array, or a function.

Comment: @FelixKling: I tried that, and it is indeed reaching that line.

@KevinB: `upload` is an object.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot and **isolate the problem**, you need to determine if this is a backend or a frontend problem.

### Backend Check

Try using something like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) to hit the endpoint directly with the data that should be posted. If you never get that `console.log` to execute then you may have some problems with your routes.

### Frontend Check

If that works, then look at the Network tab of your Dev Tools in Chrome and make sure that the request looks the same as the one you make in Postman.

Comment: -"look at the Network tab of your Dev Tools in Chrome"

That's the problem, it's not showing up there at all. Thanks for the tips, though; I'll do some more troubleshooting and see how it goes.

Comment: @beefers1 did you test the NodeJS portion by hitting the endpoint directly? If so, then this is not a node question at all.